# How to get access to children of WindowsPhone page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to get children of a current page  and their bounding boxes. I can get a page like that :

`var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content as PhoneApplicationPage;`

But I don't see the way how I can get access to the children of the page. Am I on a wrong way? How to do it properly?

note : I'm trying to do it in class lib.

Comment: Are you talking about, getting the controls within a page?

Comment: Yes, but not only controls. About getting FrameworkElement's also. I've find the way to do this but thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it this way -

```
        var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(currentPage); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(currentPage, i);

            if (child is System.Windows.Controls.Control)
            {
                // do work
            }
            else if (child is System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
            {
                // do work
            }
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(child) > 0)
            {
                enumChildren(child); // recur. enumerate children
            }
        }
```